# Why can't I undo retweet the retweets I retweeted years ago?

Tags: twitter, retweet

I've been searching for hours on how to do this. I now have my Twitter archive and I want to undo-retweet retweets years ago. I know that you can simply click on the retweet button which is in color green to undo-retweet, but I my retweet button isn't green—it's grey. I can see my profile on the who-retweeted-list, so I guess I still have it retweeted, but how can I undo it?